# Turtles hatch when crossing a line

Tags: netlogo

I want my turtles to hatch (= make one more turtle) when they cross a specific line. I have tried the command ifelse?, and I can get it to work on a simple model, when my turtles randomly wanders: If they move to a patch on the left side (xcor < 0) they die, if they make a move to a patch with xcor > 0 they hatch  1.
But I want the proces to be linked to witch patch they come from. If they stand on a patch with xcor < 0 and moves to another patch with xcor < 0 they shall die - but if they change xcor from negative to positive - they should multiply (= hatch 1). 
My problem is: Is it possible to write a code-string that "remembers" the turtles position one tick before and use it to either let the turtle die og multiply?

{

```
       to setup

 clear-all
  create-turtles 20

   ask turtles [set size 2
  set heading  random 45     ;; turtle is now facing northeast
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set color white
    set shape "person"]
end

  to go

  ask turtles

    [ rt random 360 ; turns in a random direction
      fd 4             ;; all turtles move forward one step
      rt random 180     ;; ...and turn a random amount
      fd 4
      lt random 180
  ]

  ask turtles
  [ifelse pxcor > 0
  [hatch random 2]
    [die]]
end    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a turtle variable to give each turtle a memory.

```
turtles-own 
[
  old-xcor
]
```

Just before the turtle moves, assign ‘xcor‘ to that variable.

```
To move-turtle
  Set old-xcor xcor
  < Your movement code >
  if old-xcor < 0
  [ Ifelse xcor < 0 
    [ Die ]
    [ Hatch 1 ]
  ]
End
```